# Best Redis practice for caching a list

Tags: redis

Using Redis, is it possible/plausible to cache a dynamic list query?

If I have a database with forum posts. And I want to cache the search results (which is a list of documents), should I/can I use Redis to cache these results?

Answer (score 2):

If you directly cache results for a query then you will be duplicating lot of data in your redis cache, which is not memory efficient.
You should instead use two redis structures,

1. Lists -> to store list of postids which match a search query, using LPUSH, or you can use a CSV string too instead of redis list.
2. Strings -> to store forum post content against a post id.

Example:
When a user searches for say 'caching' and you get postids 1,3,4,5,6,
when a user searches 'redis', you get postids 1,2,4,5,8

For a search 'caching' , you would store 1,3,4,5,6 in a redis list with key 'post_id_list#caching', and when you retreive it, you will do a [MGET](https://redis.io/commands/mget) for keys of 1,3,4,5,6 forum posts.
Similarly for a search 'redis', you would fetch the redis list with key 'post_id_list#redis' and then do a MGET for post keys 1,2,4,5,8.